# Rails 5: custom slugs for rails urls error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was following the tutorial on hackernoon, to generate Obfuscated URLs.

The first step is to add a slug column to the database, but I got an error.

AddSlugToReservations

```
class AddSlugToReservation < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :reservations, :slug, :string, null: false
    add_index :reservations, :slug, unique: true
  end
end
```

I get the following error when I try `rails db:migrate`

```
SQLite3::SQLException: Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL: ALTER TABLE "reservations" ADD "slug" varchar NOT NULL
```

So I change the migration file to:

```
class AddSlugToReservation < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :reservations, :slug, :string, null: false, default: 0
    change_column :reservations, :slug, :string, default: nil
    add_index :reservations, :slug, unique: true
  end
end
```

But then I encountered the following error:

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: reservations.slug: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_reservations_on_slug" ON "reservations" ("slug")
```

What should I do? I couldn't find any solution to this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with below code

```
class AddSlugToReservation < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :reservations, :slug, :string, unique: true, default: 0, null: false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class AddSlugToReservation < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :reservations, :slug, :string, unique: true
    change_column_null :reservations, :slug, false
  end
end
```

Hope it helps.